# Creating a case-insensitive and accent/diacritics insensitive search on a field

Tags: postgresql, index, full-text-search, case-sensitive, unaccent

I would like to know if it makes sense to create an index combining two functions while using Full Text Search: `lower(name)` and `f_unaccent(name)` Where `f_unaccent` is just my wrapper to make unaccent function immutable.

I do have an index working on: `f_unaccent(name)` using `varchar_pattern_ops`. My question is: would an index that combines `lower` and `unaccent` functions be triggered by full_text_search `lower(f_unaccent(name))`.

I don't know if the `lower` function would be useful working with Full Text Search algorithms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, we need to clarify a few things.

## Pattern Ops and Trigram

This type of query can work on varchar/text pattern_ops,

```
foo LIKE 'bar%'
```

Queries with [*Un-anchored search patterns*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187659/2639) reqire [`trigram`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html).

```
foo LIKE '%bar%'
```

Both of them can work on function expressions, so long as you maintain the same sequence in the query that you have in the index.

[Full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) is something completely different. It transforms your text into lexemes by stubbing to the root words, lowercasing, removing stop words, and a slew of other tricks. Keep reading:

## Unaccent by itself (wouldn't suggest it)

Unfortunately though `unaccent` is only "stable" not "immutable." And so if you try to create an index on `unaccent(text)` you'll get an error, `functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`. I assume this is why you created the wrapper `f_accent` having found that on [Erwins answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/124486). Which looks like this,

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_unaccent(text)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
SELECT public.unaccent('public.unaccent', $1)  -- schema-qualify function and dictionary
$func$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;

CREATE TABLE foo AS
  SELECT 'asdf'::text AS mytext;
CREATE INDEX ON foo (lower(f_unaccent(mytext)) text_pattern_ops);
```

Or, for trigram,

```
CREATE INDEX ON foo
USING gin(lower(f_unaccent(mytext)) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Now remember you have to carry that long sequence `lower(f_unaccent(mytext))`  through to make it work..

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE lower(f_unaccent(mytext)) LIKE '%whatever%';
```

## Unaccent with a FTS Dictionary

**Instead of that method, I would create a dictionary that uses `unaccent` and use FTS**. With custom dictionaries though it will likely do what you want. FTS converts the words to tokens which makes searching very simple and fast.

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent; -- still required it plugs into FTS.

CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION mydict ( COPY = simple );
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION mydict
  ALTER MAPPING FOR hword, hword_part, word
  WITH unaccent, simple;
```

Now you should be able to

- Removing any `varchar_pattern_ops` or `trigram` index
- if desired, create a [GIST or GIN index on the tsvector](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-indexes.html)

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ON foo USING to_tsvector('mydict', mytext);
  ```

You can see the tokens and what it's doing here,

```
select to_tsvector(
  'mydict',
  'Zoë and Renée are elected to the council of Cheese Eating Surrender Monkeys'
);
                                                             to_tsvector                                                             
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 'and':2 'are':4 'cheese':10 'council':8 'eating':11 'elected':5 'monkeys':13 'of':9 'renee':3 'surrender':12 'the':7 'to':6 'zoe':1
(1 row)
```

And you can query the table simply like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE to_tsvector('mydict', mytext) @@ 'cheese & council';
```

You don't have to use `simple` either. If the column contains statements in just one language you can use [one of the other dictionaries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html) to simplify things and remove stop words.

Comment: Hi Evan, many thanks for your response, it gives me the info I need to start tunning my searches. And yes, my wrapper function to unaccent was the one proposed by Erwin :) I think I will create a tsvector column with a gin index to search against, and will populate that column using a trigger, with the plain string column contents to_tsvector.

Comment: I wouldn't use a trigger, there is no reason for it.

Comment: From https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/208197 _weights are not included in a GIN index. So it may pay after all to include the pre-computed value in the table_