# Keep both accented and unaccented versions in a tsvector column?

Tags: postgresql, index, full-text-search, postgresql-9.6

I am facing a situation where users **SHOULD** submit items that are written in plain English. However, it happens that names have accents - coming from various languages. I have a `tsvector` column in my table which is indexed for fulltext search.

Here is the info about this column, and relevant info about the table:

```
                                                         Table "public.companies"
     Column     |          Type          |                       Modifiers                        | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id             | integer                | not null default nextval('companies_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 name           | character varying(128) | not null                                               | extended |              | 
 description    | text                   |                                                        | extended |              | 
 tsmeta         | tsvector               |                                                        | extended |              | 

Indexes:
    "companies_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id) CLUSTER
    "companies_search_idx" gin (tsmeta)
Triggers:
    companies_tsmeta_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON companies FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE companies_tsmeta_trigger()
```

Now the problem comes when the user creates a name like **français**. Not all the users have the **ç** character at hand and those who don't will have troubles finding this entry - meaning that it will be stored with the cedilla-c in the `tsvector` column. So my thought was to use the `unaccent` extension in order to strip these accents. **However** now users that just type *français* will have problems and will not find the entry. So I came up with a function that just concatenates both versions (accented and accent-stripped) of the name and descriptions. However, descriptions can get pretty large and I worry the index will take too much storage.

```
create or replace function companies_tsmeta_trigger() returns trigger as $$
begin
  new.tsmeta :=
    setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(new.name, '')), 'A') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('english', unaccent(coalesce(new.name, ''))), 'B') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(new.description, '')), 'C') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('english', unaccent(coalesce(new.description, ''))), 'D');
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

What are your suggestions?

Comment: Related, yes: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177020/creating-a-case-insensitive-and-accent-diacritics-insensitive-search-on-a-field But not a duplicate, weights are not covered.

Comment: @Victor do you have any objections to confining the question to one of weight, myself or Erwin will be happy to do it. There is something unique here -- Erwin is right about that, but I don't 80% the question and answer are already covered on this site if you don't target weight specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first impulse was this: Use an [**expression index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html) on the unaccented strings *only*. Don't store `tsmeta` in the table redundantly. So you also don't need the trigger. And certainly don't bloat the index with original *and* unaccented string. This way your table and index are smaller and faster on read and write.

**However**, The index expression needs to be `IMMUTABLE`. `setweight()` and `to_tsvector(regconfig,text)` are `IMMUTABLE`, that's good. But `unaccent()` is only `STABLE`. **Read** the detailed assessment here first:

- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

If you have multiple use cases, create the function wrapper `f_unaccent()` as instructed over there.

For just the case at hand, we can wrap the whole `tsvector` creation in a single `IMMUTABLE` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tsmeta(_a text, _b text)
  RETURNS tsvector AS
$func$
  SELECT setweight(to_tsvector('english', public.unaccent('public.unaccent', _a)), 'A')
      || setweight(to_tsvector('english', public.unaccent('public.unaccent', COALESCE(_b, ''))), 'B')
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Assuming that the additional module `unaccent` is installed in the schema `public` as explained in the linked answer.

Since `name` is defined `NOT NULL`, we don't need `COALESCE` for that column.

Then the index can look like this:

```
CREATE INDEX companies_search_idx ON companies USING gin (f_tsmeta(name, description));
```

Used in queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM companies
WHERE f_tsmeta(name, description) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'foo');
```

**On second thought**, weights are not included in a GIN index. So it may pay after all to include the pre-computed value in the table. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-indexes.html)

> GIN indexes store only the words (lexemes) of `tsvector` values, and not
>   their weight labels. Thus a table row recheck is needed when using a
>   query that involves weights.

With the demonstrated expression index, the expression has to be re-evaluated when using weights, which adds extra cost.

Redundant column or expression index, it should be an improvement to integrate the unaccent dictionary into a custom [`TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertsconfig.html) directly and build index (and table column) using that, as demonstrated by Evan in this related answer:

- [Creating a case-insensitive and accent/diacritics insensitive search on a field](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177020/creating-a-case-insensitive-and-accent-diacritics-insensitive-search-on-a-field)

Simplifies things and should be more efficient.

Comment: Everything you are proposing seems reasonable and looks like it will help me implement what I need. So I will accept your answer, although I have not tested this yet! Thank you very much! Is it ok if I come up with any later question in a comment here (related to your answer)?

Comment: @Victor: It's best to post follow-up questions as *questions* in their own right. You can always link to this question / answer for context and leave a comment here to link back (and get my attention). Except for minor details, or course, that would not warrant a new question.