# Use extra column to save an unaccented copy of a string instead of using unaccent module

Tags: postgresql, database-design, string-searching

I am heavily using the [unaccent module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html) in a table with 500.000 rows where each row contains  proportionally a lot of accented characters.

The issue I am facing is that my queries have become time consuming monsters.

Is it utterly unacceptable -in terms of database design- to save an unaccented copy of each string in another column of the table in question and query that one instead of using the unaccent module?

Comment: Unacceptable by what standard(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* store an unaccented version redundantly. And create index on that column to support your queries.

Or, better yet, to avoid bloating your table with redundant data, create a functional index on the original column.  You need an `IMMUTABLE` function for that, while `unaccent()` is only `STABLE`. Detailed instructions:

- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

Then, based on the function `f_unaccent()` from the linked answer:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_unaccent_col_idx ON tbl(public.f_unaccent(col));
```

Or some other index. Maybe use the [full text search (FTS)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) infrastructure with `unaccent` as dictionary. Example:

- [Creating a case-insensitive and accent/diacritics insensitive search on a field](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177020/creating-a-case-insensitive-and-accent-diacritics-insensitive-search-on-a-field/177044#177044)

Or use it in a trigram index:

- [Queries using GIN index on f_unaccent() seem slow?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203429/queries-using-gin-index-on-f-unaccent-seem-slow/203441#203441)
- [Why does a slight change in the search term slow down the query so much?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343860/why-does-a-slight-change-in-the-search-term-slow-down-the-query-so-much/36347677#36347677)