# Trigram similarity (pg_trgm) with German umlauts

Tags: postgresql, index, full-text-search, string-searching, unaccent

I try to figure out how to improve Postgres 10.6 pg_trgm queries with German umlauts (äöü). In german 'ö' can be written as 'oe'. But beware: not every 'oe' can be written as 'ö'.

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.names
  (name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX names_idx
    ON public.names USING gin (name COLLATE pg_catalog."default" gin_trgm_ops);
```

```
SHOW LC_COLLATE; -- de_DE.UTF-8
```

When I use the [`similarity()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.41.5)
function to query the similarity for ***'Schoenstraße'***.

```
SELECT
    name,
    similarity (name, 'Schoenstraße') AS similarity,
    show_trgm (name)
FROM
    names
WHERE
    name % 'Schoenstraße'
ORDER BY
    similarity DESC;
```

I get the following result:

```
Name            similarity  show_trgm

Schyrenstraße   0.588235    {0x9a07c3,0xde3801,""  s"","" sc"",chy,ens,hyr,nst,ren,sch,str,tra,0x76a40e,yre}
Schönstraße     0.5625      {0x9a07c3,0xde3801,0xf00320,0x095f29,""  s"","" sc"",0x6deea5,nst,sch,str,tra,0x76a40e}
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=58f8436a5096a779f358572e615bf11f)

Is there anything I can do to improve that or do I need to replace all umlauts in the DB?

Comment: Excellent, exemplary question with everything that's needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters: A German poet is still a "Poet". 'Poet' <> 'Pöt'; 'oe' <> 'ö'. The convention to replace 'ö' with 'oe' is largely out of use nowadays. See:

- https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut#Darstellung_von_Umlauten

I have had related problems many times. The [additional module **`unaccent`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) is instrumental to cover spelling variants and typos on both sides. Install it once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

See:

- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860)

The tricky part is to get index support with it. Details may be hard for beginners.

#### Trigram similarity

Then create the wrapper function as instructed here (same link again):

- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860)

Create a new index with it:

```
CREATE INDEX names_trgm_idx ON names USING gin (f_unaccent(name) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Query demo:

```sql
SELECT name
     , similarity(f_unaccent(name), f_unaccent('Schoenstraße')) AS sim_unaccent
     , similarity(name, 'Schoenstraße') AS sim
FROM   names
WHERE  f_unaccent(name) % f_unaccent('Schoenstraße')
ORDER  BY f_unaccent(name) <-> f_unaccent('Schoenstraße')
        , name <-> 'Schoenstraße';  -- best match first
```

Sorting by `name <-> 'Schoenstraße'` *additionally* serves as tiebreaker to get best matches first (*after* filtering cheaply with the index).

Consider a GiST index instead of GIN for "nearest neighbor"-type queries with `LIMIT`. See:

- [Best index for similarity function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103821/best-index-for-similarity-function/103823#103823)

#### Full text search (FTS or just TS)

Consider [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) to just match complete words (after stemming), or with prefix matching / phrase search ... See:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

The `unaccent` module provides a dictionary for integration in a [`TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-configuration.html):

```sql
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION de (COPY = german);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION de
ALTER MAPPING FOR hword, hword_part, word WITH unaccent, german_stem;
```

Index based on it:

```
CREATE INDEX names_fts_idx ON names USING GIN (to_tsvector('de', name));
```

Alternatively, since you are dealing with *names*, you might base it on the `simple` text search configuration instead of `german`. No stop words, no stemming. Names don't necessarily follow language-specific rules.

Query demo:

```sql
SELECT name
     , ts_lexize('unaccent', name)
     , to_tsvector('de', name)
     , to_tsquery('de', 'Schoenstraße')
     , to_tsvector('de', name) @@ to_tsquery('de', 'Schoenstraße') AS match
     , similarity(name, 'Schoenstraße')
FROM   names
WHERE  to_tsvector('de', name) @@ to_tsquery('de', 'Schoenstraße')
ORDER  BY name <-> 'Schoenstraße';  -- exact matches first
```

Again, sorting by `name <-> 'Schoenstraße'` serves as tiebreaker, maybe *additionally* to other sort criteria.

Note, however, that looking for 'Schoenstraße' with FTS does *not* find 'Schönstraße', as `unaccent()` does not change 'oe', and maps 'ö' to 'o'. ('oe' <> 'ö').

Related:

- [Creating a case-insensitive and accent/diacritics insensitive search on a field](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177020/creating-a-case-insensitive-and-accent-diacritics-insensitive-search-on-a-field/177044#177044)
- [Finding the most commonly used non-stop words in a column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145016/finding-the-most-commonly-used-non-stop-words-in-a-column/186754#186754)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a81a37576b9568515ed7f580e6904fc2)*  -- looking for 'Schoenstraße'

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2299b0a0352d7cc6ca5f1efa835e7a92)*  -- looking for 'Schönstraße'

Comment: Perfect detailed answer. But could you change `Schönstraße` to `Schoenstraße` in your query examples? Because that is the explained scenario in my question and not other way around.

Comment: fiddle pg_trgm only [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=58f8436a5096a779f358572e615bf11f) **VS** fiddle pg_trgm with "accent insensitive” collations [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ee0ef73b701af12ba8ae81033c1dfed1)

Comment: Changed it to 'Schoenstraße' accordingly - and added notes for FTS and "nearest neighbor" queries.